# Copying Data from one workbook to another while both are open

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I am attempting to copy data from one open workbook to another open workbook. I keep getting a Run-time error 1004: essentially saying my workbook can't be found. I have this intuition that because I am using a GXL pull software on one of the workbooks(spreadsheet server) it is complicating my ability to pull the data.The debugger seems to say it is Set x = Workbook.open line of the code. Here is the sample of my code thus far,

```
Sub CopyPasteData()
'
'CopyPasteData Macro
'

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.open("C:\\Client\C$\Users\ffffllll01\Desktop\North MC Macro Test.xlsm")
Set y = Workbooks.open("C:\\Users\ffffllll01\Desktop\Test Booklet for MC% Data Copy.xlsm")

x.Sheets("North MFG MC% Masonry).Range("W16:W21").Copy

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

'
End Sub
```

Comment: C:\\ is never going to be a valid path in Windows.

Comment: This is the file that is utilizing the Spreadsheet Server data pull; do you think having a workbook that has that software functionality enabled precludes one from utilizing macros? My thought process is if I can manually copy from that workbook to one in excel I should be able to use a macro.

Answer (score 0):

3 things at a glance:

1. I don't like the "%" in the file name.
2. You're missing the closing quotes in line 12, should be:

   x.Sheets("North MFG MC% Masonry").Range("W16:W21").Copy
3. I think you should enter some arguments for PasteSpecial in line 14.

Hope this was useful. Regards